# Scope of variables in parallel R package snowfall

Tags: r, snowfall

As my understanding, the slave processes cannot access variables in the global/parent environments in R package snowfall.

For example, the code below will give an error message as I expected:

```
parfun <- function(i, var1, var2) {
    return(var3)
}

var3 <- 'VAR3'
library(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 2)
res <- sfLapply(seq(1, 2), parfun, 'VAR1', 'VAR2')
res
```

The error message:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'var3' not found
```

However, there is no error message when parallel codes in another function.

```
fun1 <- function(var1, var2, var3) {
    parfun <- function(i, var1, var2) {
        return(var3)
    }
    library(snowfall)
    sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus = 2)
    res <- sfLapply(seq(1, 2), parfun, var1, var2)
    res
}

fun1('VAR1', 'VAR2', 'VAR3')
```

The results are as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] "VAR3"

[[2]]
[1] "VAR3"
```

I don't understand this behavior as `var3` doesn't exist in the function `parfun`, but in his parent environment `fun1`.

Could somebody explain to me? Thanks for any suggestions.